# CGZip.dll referenced but objects of class still undefined

Tags: dll, vb6, visual-studio-2005

Hope you could assist me with this problem. I am maintaining an existing application. The problem is it using a dll CGZip.dll for unzipping archive folders. I downloaded the dll from the net and tried to add it as reference but got this error:

> A Reference to '../CGZip.dll' could not be added. Please make sure
>   that file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM
>   component.

Can anyone please help me in the right direction? Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
Ok So i found out that this problem is because you have to register the dll first in System32. So I registered both dll and no longer getting the error problem on run time.

But when it hits this code block:

```
Dim oUnZip As New CGZipLibrary.CGUnzipFiles
```

It displays this error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {293364AE-43F8-11D3-BC2D-4000000A2806} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154.

Comment: Ok, then my assumptions were wrong. Next Question: Are you working with VB6 or VB.NET. VB6 ist strict 32bit, while VB.NET allows 32 and 64 bit. And then you have to register the correct OCX. When you are on 64 bit Windows, and you registered the 32 bit OCX, it will not work, unless you set the cpu type to 'x86'

Comment: Did you also get the zip32.dll, and unzip32.dll files that the CGZipLibrary wraps?

Comment: @ThomasKrojer Thank You!!! Your my God. Cant believe i hit the 32 <> 64 wall. Ive seen this problem too much times to be fooled. But thanks man. Please Add this as answer so I can accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- made comment to answer -

Ok, then my assumptions were wrong. Next Question: Are you working with VB6 or VB.NET. VB6 ist strict 32bit, while VB.NET allows 32 and 64 bit. And then you have to register the correct OCX. When you are on 64 bit Windows, and you registered the 32 bit OCX, it will not work, unless you set the cpu type to 'x86'